# How to make a PDF and a Conditional PDF in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, time-series

So, this might sound a bit naive.

I have a time series of values. (Say: 1-10000)

I have no other information. How can I generate a PDF in matlab?

I have figured out the way to calculate a cdf using cdfplot.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're assuming the data points are drawn from a Normal Distribution?

Comment: They are probably not from a normal distribution. I intend to fit a long-normal III distribution. What should I do if it is not normal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you say that normcdf worked to calculate the cdf

then normpdf would work for the pdf  [normpdf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html)

that's given the knowledge that the samples are from a normal distribution

you can estimate the mean and variance using [normfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normfit.html)

Comment: Apologies for the miscommunication. cdfplot worked for me, not normcdf. Normcdf output doesn't look anything like a CDF for my data.